# Union two tables having unix_timestamp() function in both

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have two tables A and B. Both has same column names. I want to merge these two table and load it to table C. Table C also have same column names as A and B and one more column in timestamp (this for capturing the merged time). I dont want duplicates in Table C.  I tried union but getting duplicate values because one of the column in Table C in Timestamp data type.

For Example, below is my sample query

```
insert overwrite table TableC 
select field1,field2, unix_timestamp() as field3 from table_A
UNION
select field1,field2, unix_timestamp() as field3 from table_B
```

The two unix_timestamp() function returns different timestamps (just a milli second difference) and I am getting duplicate data because of the timestamp.

Is there anyother way to get the same timestamp for both functions while union ?

Comment: You can insert NULL in the timestamp field and then execute: update TableC set field3=unix_timestamp() where field3 is null

Comment: @GiacomoDegliEsposti Thanks for your suggestion . I myself found the workaround. i tried like below and it worked.
`insert overwrite table TableC
select T1.field1,T1.field2,unix_timestamp() as field3
from
(select field1,field2 from table_A
UNION
select field1,field2 from table_B) AS T1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> unix_timestamp()
>   Gets current Unix timestamp in seconds.
>   This function is
>   non-deterministic and prevents proper optimization of queries -
>   this has been deprecated since 2.0 in favour of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

```
insert overwrite table TableC 
select field1,field2, unix_timestamp(current_timestamp) as field3 from table_A
UNION
select field1,field2, unix_timestamp(current_timestamp) as field3 from table_B
```

---

Additional work-arounds

```
insert overwrite table TableC 

select      field1,field2,unix_timestamp() as field3

from        (         select field1,field2 from table_A
            union all select field1,field2 from table_B
            ) t

group by    field1,field2
```

or

```
insert overwrite table TableC 

select      field1,field2,unix_timestamp() as field3

from        (     select field1,field2 from table_A
            union select field1,field2 from table_B
            ) t
```

Comment: why I need `group by` ? without `group by` it worked fine!

Comment: BTW. This is terrible. I wasn't aware of this issue and I have just verified it on my VM. Thank you for bringing it up :-)

Comment: P.s. Notice that when I used GROUP BY I also used UNION **ALL**

Comment: unix_timestamp() is non-deterministic and calculated for all rows. Use current_timestamp if it's ok for you to have one value per query execution.

Comment: @leftjoin - Note to self - RTFM. I actually had it open in front of my eyes